# Regular Expression for Currency (no dollar sign, has comma, has decimal, optional parentheses for negatives)

Tags: c#, regex

I apologize if this post is repetitive but I've searched extensively and can't seem to find a solution that works.

I am working on a regular expression for C#. Here are the criteria to match:

- Currency
- No dollar sign
- Comma for 1000 separator
- Decimal
- Only two digits after the decimal
- Parentheses for negative numbers

A couple of examples:

```
  1,024.12
    500.00
 10,456.23
      2.89
 (8,456.15)
     (1.63)
```

This is the current pattern I am using:

```
^\(?\d+\,?\d+[.]{1}\d{2}\)?
```

I think this pattern would do the trick, however, there is a string built out of numbers and periods on the same line that matches this pattern. Example:

```
123.1234.12345.123456789.12345.123
```

I know this is pretty basic stuff but I'm having trouble getting it to only match the currency portion and not the string above.

Thanks for any suggestions you can provide

Comment: Don't use `\d` for digits in .NET, unless you want to include `० १ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ ` Hindi digits :-) Use `[0-9]`

Comment: Is the thousands separator optional, in other words: is this accepted `12345.00` ?

Comment: Thanks xanatos. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current expression won't match the fourth `2.89` and the sixth example `(1.63)` in your list.

Instead you can use the following expression:

```
^(\()?[0-9]+(?>,[0-9]{3})*(?>\.[0-9]{2})?(?(1)\))$
```

This expression matches start-of-line `^`, then it tries to match an optional parentheses `(` for negative numbers, the parentheses is captured in a group for a reason that will be cleared soon.

Now it tries to match one or more numbers `[0-9]+`, this should cover all whole numbers like `234`, `5652`, etc ..

Then it looks for a possible comma *(thousands separator)* `,` followed by 3 digits `(?>,[0-9]{3})*` repeated zero or more times, this covers numbers that contain thousand separators.

Then it tries to find a decimal point `.` followed by exactly 2 digits `(?>\.[0-9]{2})?` which is of course optional and this covers decimal numbers.

After that, the expression uses `(?(1)\))` *- the conditional construct `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` -* so that if we actually matched an open parentheses then we should match a closing one, this prevents the expression from matching incorrect negative numbers such as `(2.4` with no closing parentheses.

Finally comes the end-of the-string `$` to prevent partial matches such as your last example.

**[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/gB7rO6)**

Comment: @Sniffer- I think this is going to do the trick. Right now it gets me past the string it was hanging up on before but matching some other numeric identifiers on the same line (I didn't mention this in my OP). I've been trying to modify it to require the decimal. Could you provide any pointers on how to do this? Thx

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue You mean you want the decimal part to be mandatory rather than optional, this will make numbers like `123142` or `34,123`, etc .. unacceptable ?

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue If you really want this then just remove the question mark `?` after this group `(?>\.[0-9]{2})?` so it becomes `(?>\.[0-9]{2})`.

Comment: @Sniffer- That was the change I was making too but it fails to match anything when I remove the `?`. I may be doing something wrong so I'm going to keep playing with it a little longer and will post back the results.

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue Try it in the demo link I gave you and you will see it works.

Comment: @Sniffer- Yeah it definitely works in that link you gave me. Do you know if the PHP regex engine is the same as .NET? If not no worries I am researching it on my own right now.

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue They work the same way in this case, I am certain of that. Pay attention you **must** test each sample input individually and watch out for newline `\n` and carriage return `\r` characters at the end of each input string as they might cause the match attempt to fail.

Comment: It turns out I was making a stupid, sloppy error when I was parsing the line to read. My apologies for wasting so much of your time. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to help me on this. I need to pick up a good book on RegEx and study up!

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue Happy I could help. Don't worry about this, we all commit sloppy mistakes that make us bump our head into the wall when we figure out what was wrong :). Just keep practicing and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `$` to the end of your regex, so you'll get

```
^\(?\d+\,?\d+[.]{1}\d{2}\)?$
```

That way you will at least only match numbers with exactly 2 digits after the `.` and the string you mentioned, shouldn't match anymore.

Comment: Thanks Vince. I tested this pattern on my limited data set and it works as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
\(?\b[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}\b\)?
```

Hover over the expression [here](http://regexr.com?365h9) to have an explanation.

Comment: David - I tested this on a limited data set and it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a good solution for you:

```
^\(?(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]*))\.[0-9]{2}\)?$
```

This will prevent numbers that don't make much sense such as `004,2.42`

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the graph?

Comment: Thanks smerny, this pattern works on my data set as well. And that graph is definitely cool/helpful to understanding RegEx. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is just to parse a decimal, [decimal.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb.aspx) or [decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) with a properly set [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) will do what you need.

```
const NumberStyles numberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowParentheses
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
decimal parsed;
var successful = decimal.TryParse(s, numberStyles, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out parsed);
```

Complete test:

```
var values = new[]
    {
        "1,024.12",
        "500.00", 
        "10,456.23", 
        "2.89", 
        "(8,456.15)", 
        "(1.63)", 
        "123.1234.12345.123456789.12345.123"
    };

const NumberStyles numberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowParentheses
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
                                    | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

foreach (var s in values)
{
    decimal parsed;
    var successful = decimal.TryParse(s, numberStyles, culture, out parsed);

    Console.WriteLine("Successful? {0}; Parsed = {1}", 
        successful, 
        successful ? parsed.ToString() : "?");
}
```

Output:

```
Successful? True; Parsed = 1024.12
Successful? True; Parsed = 500.00
Successful? True; Parsed = 10456.23
Successful? True; Parsed = 2.89
Successful? True; Parsed = -8456.15
Successful? True; Parsed = -1.63
Successful? False; Parsed = ?
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. At first glance it looks like it will do what I need it to. I need to try and digest it a little more to figure out if it is a better solution than using a RegEx match. If not I'm sure it will be useful in the future on other projects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
^\(?\d+\,?\d+[.]{1}\d{2}\)?\\>
```

or

```
^\(?\d+\,?\d+[.]{1}\d{2}\)?\b
```

so that it doesn't match on partial hits.

Comment: In your first regex, were you trying to use `\>` as an end-of-word boundary?  That's not supported in the .NET flavor.  (Also, I'm guessing you used two backslashes there because it wasn't displaying correctly with only one, and @smemy should have deleted one of them when he activated code formatting.)

Comment: I tested both of these and as Alan pointed out, the first one didn't work (maybe just a formatting error) but the second one did. Thank you for the suggestion.