# Match currency with negatives in parens or prefixed with "-"

Tags: regex

I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535253/2237785) that presents a regex pattern to match currency values where numbers are grouped with `,` and may or may not contain a decimal followed by two decimal places. It also matches negative numbers enclosed in parens `()`. That pattern is:

```
^(\()?[0-9]+(?>,[0-9]{3})*(?>\.[0-9]{2})?(?(1)\))$
```

I'm looking to match this exact pattern except I would also like to account for negative numbers that are prefixed with `-` instead of enclosed in `()` (but not both). So negative numbers might be represented as `-123.45` or `(123.45)` but not `(-123.45)` or `-(123.45)`.

I've created [this regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/tC3qR7/2) with the pattern shown above and some examples of matches that I would like to match, as well as some I would like *not* to match.

For example, it should match:

```
  123.45
1,234.56
 (123.45)
   -1.00
```

But should not match:

```
123.456
-16.1
(-1.23)
```

I thought maybe I could just begin the pattern with `^(\(|\-)?` to match a `(` or `-` and then the conditional construct would take care of matching the closing `)` only if an opening `(` was found, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fairly close. You can use a non-capturing group at start:

```
^(?:(\()|-)?\d+(?>,[0-9]{3})*(?>\.[0-9]{2})?(?(1)\))$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC3qR7/3)

Comment: So it's the non-capture group `?:(\()` that allows it to work properly with the conditional `?(1)` reference at the end? The non-capture group is defining `(` as capture group `1`?

Comment: Non-capturing group leaves `(` in group#1 hence your last conditional match for `)` still works.